# Return value in except block of context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I try understand context manager. Peoples wtite that it is equivalent to `try...finally` block.

Does exist ability write following code with context manager?

```
def func():
    try:
        do_something1()
        ...
    except Exception:
        return False
    do_something2()
    return True
```

Another words, I would stoped of excecution `func` if exception thrown.

```
def func():
    with context()
        do_something1()
        ...
    do_something2()
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
class MyContextManager(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        do_something1()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        do_something2()

with MyContextManager():
    func()
```

Comment: You call `do_something2` and `do_something1` in `MyContextManager`. It is very strange. I added a example to my question what i want.